# Обработка ссылок php

Tags: php

На страничке имеется форма заполнения резюме. Каждый заносится в базу mysql. Под формой надо выводить список текущих резюме. Каждая ссылка (ФИО) - просмотр резюме. Как снизу генерить ссылки и обрабатывать их на php. Типа как в форме action указал и все. Ну я узнаю количество и добавлю. Что должна содержать ссылка? Я так понимаю на один файл, который все обработает. А как в нем узнать с какой ссылки был переход? Можно ссылки где почитать.

П.С. Я только недавно начал изучать php)

Comment: @Андрей Бакша, ленитесь вы, батенька. Это если бы вы учились играть в шахматы, прочитали в книге первую строчку: "В шахматах есть фигуры и доска", отложили книгу и начали бы засыпать других вопросами. Основы изучите и я вас уверяю, что очень много вопросов сами собой отпадут. А так вы и себя, и других замучаете.

Comment: Основы-то я изучил. Остальное все реализовал. Остался список. Просто нет опыта. Вот набираюсь...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выводим ссылку, в качестве `$user_id` задаем уникальный идентификатор пользователя (резюме), который хранится в базе, `$user_name` имя пользователя либо любая другая информация

```
echo '<a href="/somefile.php?user_id=',$user_id,'">',$user_name,'</a>';
```

**somefile.php:**

здесь `id` пользователя будет в переменной `$_GET['user_id']`, по этому идентификатору и находим нужного пользователя(резюме) в базе и выводим необходимую информацию.

Comment: Примерно так и представлял. Спасибо.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Сорри, нажал палец вверх. Не знал)

Comment: @FLK, только не запятые для конкатенации строк, а точки.
И неплохо бы было проверять что $_GET['user_id'] это число =)